NFTables selectively routing traffic through wireguard peer: mangle or policy based routing?
I am trying to solve a problem by mangling nexthop in nftables, but trying to add a rule to set nexthop returned an error that seems to indicate nexthop cannot be mangled.
Can nexthop be mangled?
The problem I want to solve:
I have 2 servers connected via wireguard, call them machines A and B.
Machine A is a webserver that is publically accessible. I use wireguard to connect guest C (my phone) to it.
Machine B is a server inside my home network that is connected to B via wireguard.
I have nftables set up successfully to route requests to my home subnet (192.168.1.0/24) from C (and any other peers connected to A via wireguard) through A then through B then to the relevant host on my home network. This works for several services, e.g., home assistant and ssh.
What I want now is to have C route all traffic through A then through B to my home network and open web.
For this I believe B is already sufficiently set up as it has masquerade enabled for forwarded wireguard packets. I just need A to route packets from C to B, while normal packets from A are routed normally straight to its public network interface.
Is mangling the right tool for this?
Or should I use policy based routing? This is something I have seen in a couple answers, but also discouraged in those answers: https://serverfault.com/questions/1100976/routing-fwmark-to-vpn-gateway-using-nftables-mark

Is this the problem you're trying to solve?: https://www.procustodibus.com/blog/2022/06/multi-hop-wireguard/#internet-gateway-as-a-spoke
